# jquery ajax validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have one inquiry page in my site and i am using jquery ajax validation on it.

My code is :

```
<script>
                    function sendContact() {
                        var valid;  
                        valid = validateContact();
                        if(valid) {
                            jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "contact-post.php",
                            data:'userName='+$("#userName").val()+'&userEmail='+$("#userEmail").val()+'&subject='+$("#subject").val()+'&contentsub='+$("#contentsub").val(),
                            type: "POST",
                            success:function(data){
                            $("#mail-status").html(data);
                            },
                            error:function (){}
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    function validateContact() {
                        var valid = true;   
                        $(".textbox").css('background-color','');
                        $(".error").html('');

                        if(!$("#userEmail").val()) {
                            $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
                            $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#D2434E');
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        if(!$("#contentsub").val()) {
                            $("#content-info").html("(required)");
                            $("#contentsub").css('background-color','#D2434E');
                            valid = false;
                        }   
                        return valid;
                    }
                    </script>
                 <div class="contact-form" id="frmContact">
                   <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                     <div id="mail-status"></div>
                     <div class="left_form">
                        <div>
                            <span><label>NAME</label></span>
                            <span><input name="userName" id="userName" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>E-MAIL  <span class='error' id="userEmail-info" style="color:#C40401;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;"></span><font color="#C40401">*</font></label></span>
                            <span><input name="userEmail" id="userEmail" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>PHONE</label></span>
                            <span><input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_form">
                        <div>                           
                            <span><label>SUBJECT  <span class='error' id="content-info" style="color:#C40401;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;"></span><font color="#C40401">*</font></label></span>
                            <span><textarea name="contentsub" id="contentsub"> </textarea></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="submit">
                            <span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton" onClick="sendContact();"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
```

My problem is when I click the button without any value it will only display error(required) message for E-MAIL and not for SUBJECT,how it's happen?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Did you mean that you don't understand why the messages appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have an blank space on your textarea declaration

```
<textarea name="contentsub" id="contentsub"> </textarea>
--------------------------------------------^
```

So the length is equal to one.

You can remove the blank space to correct the problem

```
<textarea name="contentsub" id="contentsub"></textarea>
```

Demo :

```js
if(!$("#contentsub").val())
    document.write('KO');

if(!$("#contentsub2").val())
    document.write('OK');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="contentsub" id="contentsub"> </textarea>
<textarea name="contentsub" id="contentsub2"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sendContact() {
                        var valid;  
                        valid = validateContact();
                        if(valid) {
                            alert("valid data");
                        }
                        else{
                          alert("invalid data");
                          }
                    }

                    function validateContact() {
                        var valid = true;   
                        $(".textbox").css('background-color','');
                        $(".error").html('');

                        if(!$("#userEmail").val()) {
                            $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
                            $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#D2434E');
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        if($.trim($("#contentsub").val()).length == 0) {
                            $("#content-info").html("(required)");
                            $("#contentsub").css('background-color','#D2434E');
                            valid = false;
                        }   
                        return valid;
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-form" id="frmContact">
                   <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                     <div id="mail-status"></div>
                     <div class="left_form">
                        <div>
                            <span><label>NAME</label></span>
                            <span><input name="userName" id="userName" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>E-MAIL  <span class='error' id="userEmail-info" style="color:#C40401;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;"></span><font color="#C40401">*</font></label></span>
                            <span><input name="userEmail" id="userEmail" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span><label>PHONE</label></span>
                            <span><input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right_form">
                        <div>                           
                            <span><label>SUBJECT  <span class='error' id="content-info" style="color:#C40401;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;"></span><font color="#C40401">*</font></label></span>
                            <span><textarea name="contentsub" id="contentsub"> </textarea></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="submit">
                            <span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="myButton" onClick="sendContact();"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
```

Instead of :

```
if(!$("#contentsub").val())
```

Can you please try:

```
if($.trim($("#contentsub").val()).length == 0)
```

Comment: nothing happen after blank submit,not even for E-MAIL.